# Pandas cannot read excel data as string

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to read a series of xls files in a loop and create a master dataframe. While all files have same columns, in some files, a column is a string while in others, it is int. I want to read all of it as string to prevent any problems.
Pandas read the first file, but all the others show up as Nan,NaT in my dataframe. What did I do wrong?

```
for f in glob.glob("C:\Consoildated_DailyReports\Hold*.xlsx"):
    df = pd.read_excel(f,sheet_name='Data')
    df = df.astype(str)
    #df.to_html()
    data1 = data1.append(df,ignore_index=True)

data1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`pd.read_excel(..., dtype={"col_name": object})` can do it! This is an argument that lets you specify how `pandas` reads the data type as it reads.

```
for f in glob.glob("C:\Consoildated_DailyReports\Hold*.xlsx"):
    df = pd.read_excel(f,sheet_name='Data', dtype={"col_name": object})
    df = df.astype(str)
    #df.to_html()
    data1 = data1.append(df,ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: Thanks. Still does not work. And when I try to write the final data1 to an excel, I only get the result of reading the first file.

Comment: Is the glob properly populating?